# How does the synthesizer decides on bitwdith for intermediate results?

Tags: verilog

Consider the following module:

```
 module power(input  [11-1:0] xi,xq,output [22-1:0] y);
    assign y = xi*xi + xq*xq;
  endmodule
```

I know that my single assignment is actually decomposed of 3 steps: 2 squares and one addition. My question is  how would the synthesizer decides on the bitwidth of the intermediate steps `xi*xi` and `xq*xq`?

I noticed that when running *logic equivelance circuit (lec)* for the above code, it causes trouble and could only be solved by decomposing the single assignment into three assignments as follows:

```
 module power(input  [11-1:0] xi,xq,output [22-1:0] yy);
    wire [21-1:0] pi,pq;
    assign pi = xi*xi;
    assign pq = xq*xq;
    assign yy = pi+pq;
  endmodule
```

Comment: Please remove the VHDL tag.

Comment: I think it is the same issue for any HDL language

Comment: Matthew Taylor's answer demonstrates the issue is not identical for both HDLs.

Comment: well since the answer covers both HDLs, it doesn't hurt to add the VHDL tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how your *simulator* decides on bitwdith for intermediate results.

**Verilog Simulation**

This expression - `assign y = xi*xi + xq*xq;` - is an example of a *context determined expression*. A Verilog simulator takes the widest of all the nets or variables in the expression and uses that. So, in your code, the widest is `y` at 22 bits wide, so Verilog will use 22 bits throughout.

**VHDL Simulation**

The behaviour of a VHDL simulator depends on the package used. If you use the `numeric_std` package, as is recommended, then you would need to obey the following rules:

> The width of the sum should be the same as the wider of the two operands.
>   The width of the product should be the sum of the widths of the operands.

Therefore, your code would compile if translated directly into VHDL:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity power is
  port (xi, xq : in  signed(11-1 downto 0);
        y      : out signed(22-1 downto 0));
end entity power;

architecture A of power is
begin
  y <= xi*xi + xq*xq;
end architecture A;
```

**Shouldn't everything be signed?**

Given the names of your module (`power`) and inputs (`xi` and `xq`) and having spent 25 years designing radio systems, shouldn't they be `signed`? Shouldn't your Verilog be:

```
module power(input signed [11-1:0] xi,xq,output signed [22-1:0] y);
   assign y = xi*xi + xq*xq;
endmodule
```

That is why I chose the `signed` type from `numeric_std`, not the `unsigned` type.

**Synthesis**

Well, I've waffled on about simulators, but you asked about synthesis. And, to be frank, I don't know what a synthesiser would do. But, given the job of a synthesiser is to design a logic circuit that behaves exactly like the simulation, you would think that any self-respecting synthesiser would use the same bit-widths as the simulator. So, I'm pretty sure that's your answer.

Comment: I actually declared the variables as signed in my design, that's why i didn't need the extra bit:

Comment: @Mortada Yes, because you're squaring it, the answer is always going to be positive. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: actually ceil(log2((2^(11-1)-1)^2+(2^(11-1)-1)^2)) is 21, plus one bit for sign  makes it 22 bits. That said, it doesn't matter whether the answer is positive or not: I have one bit for the sign